# Text in textbox does not show when printing page unless page is reloaded

Tags: html, printing, textbox

I have a webpage with some textboxes. When someone enters text I save the text with ajax when onblur occurs.

If I try to print this page the text doesn't make it to the printed page. However, if I reload the page, thus fetching the text from the database before rendering the page, the text is displayed on the printed page.

So, changes in textboxes don't appear until I reload the page. However I have a tinymce-textbox and changes to this one makes it to the printed page!

What is done differently between the "regular" textbox and the tinymce-textbox and how can I implement the same behaviour in my normal textbox so the user doesn't have to reload the page before printing it?

Comment: That shouldn't happen; unless your script somehow re-sets the values. Consider proividing some code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually sure if I'm answering my question but I noticed that where the print showed the correct values in textboxes I used a pattern that onblur on the textbox I saved and re-fetched the same data thereby setting the value back to the same value.

A tad unnecessary perhaps but where I tried to minimize network load by not re-fetching the data I didn't get the correct value in the textbox when printing the page.

So the pattern to make it work is to save and rewrite the text back to the textbox. Still seems strange but atleast it solved my problem.